# Model string property null on submit in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My model looks like:

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();
        }

        public List<MyClass> MyClasses{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required.")]
        public string Prop1{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required.")]
        public int Prop2{ get; set; }
    }
```

My controller on post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionOnPost(MyViewModel model)
{
//save to DB
//Prop2 is not null but Prop1 is nulll. why??
}
```

View code:

> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop2) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>
>   m.Prop2)
>
> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>
>   m.Prop1)

I can see `Prop2` value on submit but `Prop1` is `null`. Any idea?

Comment: I could see both the values on submit. I've tried with your viewmodel and textboxes as well

Comment: It is simple though don't see value. ModelState.IsValid is false. It says Prop1 is empty.

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]

This is your answer. Add this to every string in your code, and it will work perfectly!

Comment: Add this just like you have added the Required tag. After adding it, you will get an empty string instead of null.

Comment: Sorry, why should I see empty or null when am typing in something?

Comment: Dear I guess you must have got null only when you posted empty Prop1 textbox. If you fill the textbox with some value and then post it, I am sure you will get it on the server-side.
I am not sure about your problem, are you getting null even if you fill some value in textbox?